# Ordering of compiled TypeScript files with Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, typescript, gulp

I'm having a build pipeline based on Gulp. I use TypeScript to write Angular 1.x code. In general I follow such process:

1. Write code
2. Compile it to JavaScript
3. Use **gulp-inject** to inject files into index.html and use it in development environment:

a. I read files

b. apply **[gulp-narutal-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-natural-sort)** to have stable ordering of input files for next step

c. apply **[gulp-angular-filesort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-filesort)** to have ordering of files

Everything worked ok, but I've introduced some inheritance of clases in TypeScript. Now my index html has wrong order of dependencies:

- right.leg.js (has RightLeg class declared, child of **Leg** )
- left.leg.js (has LeftLeg class declared, child of **Leg** )
- leg.js (definition of **Leg** class)

And I got **errors** for child classes:

```
right.leg.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

that are caused by the ordering of the files.

**Question: How to resolve this kind of file sorting problem?**

*Maybe there is some kind of good plugin for gulp?*

Comment: I would recommend you to use _hard_ dependency declarations and use a tool like `tsc` or `browserify` to transverse the files in the correct order.

Comment: This is a good question, and it needs to be fixed. I thought angular-filesort would fix it but it does not..